# Replacing a paragraph with a new one in Word Add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am trying to specify a paragraph and replace it in my Word Add-in project using Javascript.
I am building the add-in from a template generated by the yeoman generator. I am doing this but it is not working so I don't really know if what I am trying to achieve is really possible:

```
const allParagraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
  context.load(allParagraphs, ['items', 'text']);
  return context.sync().then(()=>{

        allParagraphs.items[4].insertParagraph("This is a new paragraph replacing the old one in this location", Word.InsertLocation.replace);


    }
  }).then(context.sync);
```

If this is not the way to go about it please what is the right thing to do? My Add-in is being design to support Word 2016 and above so the maximum API sets I am using stops at those supporting Word 2016.

Comment: In your code, the variable `i` is never initialized. You need to have a number there or else this line needs to be in a loop that iterates over `i`.

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks for the observation. That was actually a mistake. `i` is actually meant to be a specified number. I just effected the correction by editing the question accordingly.

Comment: Please try your code in the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862) tool and see if you get an errors. Also, please clarify why it doesn't work. Is the original paragraph still there?

Comment: @RickKirkham okay. I will try that and get back. Yes the original paragraph is still there.

Comment: @RickKirkham, I got to realize that the problem is coming from the Office Word 2016 host app I am using. The problem finally got resolved when I downloaded and installed updates for the app.